# Why am I getting blank values on the matched column for a FULL OUTER JOIN?

Tags: sql, outer-join

I have two tables I'm trying to combine together.  For simplicity's sake, they have two columns each: an ID that is common across the tables, and a numerical value that is distinct.  However, not all IDs are present in both tables, hence my use of a FULL OUTER JOIN.

```
 Table1               Table2
+------+--------+    +------+--------+
| ID   | Value1 |    | ID   | Value2 |
+------+--------+    +------+--------+
| ABC  | 125    |    | ABC  | 317    |
| DEF  | 13     |    | HIJ  | 95     |
+------+--------+    +------+--------+
```

I was hoping the OUTER JOIN would give me all records like so:

```
+------+--------+--------+
| ID   | Value1 | Value2 |
+------+--------+--------+
| ABC  | 125    | 317    |
| DEF  | 13     |        |
| HIJ  |        | 95     |
+------+--------+--------+
```

But what I'm seeing instead is the ID is not copied over to the merged result if it doesn't exist in Table1:

```
+------+--------+--------+
| ID   | Value1 | Value2 |
+------+--------+--------+
| ABC  | 125    | 317    |
| DEF  | 13     |        |
|      |        | 95     |
+------+--------+--------+
```

Why would my ID be blank?  My query is as follows:

```
SELECT ID, Value1, Value2
FROM Table1
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID == Table2.ID;
```

I'm using a company-internal language closest to SQL Server. While there a few differences, I thought I would check my understanding of join syntax first.

Comment: Key and foreign-key columns are not magically combined in SQL. You need to either explicitly use `COALESCE` or modify your consuming program to accept two key columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE( Table1.ID, Table2.ID ) AS [ID],
    Table1.Value1,
    Table2.Value2
FROM
    Table1
    FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
```

Answer (score 2):

First, your query is syntactically invalid in any database that I know of.  Each table in the `FROM` has a column named `ID`.  Hence, an unqualified `ID` in the `SELECT` is ambiguous -- it is unknown which table it comes from.

Second, if you had `SELECT table1.ID, table2.ID`, then you would see what is happening.  When an `ID` is in one table but not the other, then the other value would be `NULL`.

Many databases support the ANSI standard `using` clause.  With this, you can do:

```
SELECT ID, Value1, Value2
FROM Table1 FULL OUTER JOIN
     Table2 
     USING (ID);
```

The alternative is to use the `COALESCE()` function.